# Jquery pop up on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `bpopup` jquery plugin foe all pop ups. I have below code.

```
$dialogWindow.bPopup({
        fadeSpeed: 'fast', //can be a string ('slow'/'fast') or int
        followSpeed: 1500, //can be a string ('slow'/'fast') or int
        modalClose: true,
        opacity: 0.6,
        position: [200, 350] //x, y
    });
```

Above code is working. I want the pop up to be shown only one time after the application page is loaded. But it is popping up even on URL change. How can I avoid popping up on URL change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'll need something to remember that is has already been popped up once before. I would guess that the easiest approach is to do this backend, with PHP or whatever. Check if a session variable "hasPopped" is true (just an example), and if not, set a class to the popup, ie "to-be-popped".

Then you'll just do $('.to-be-popped').bPopup( { ... } ); instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am using Java.

Comment: I'd think you can set session variables in java too ;)